# Java: Type mismatch error iterating through a generic HashSet<E>

Tags: java, loops, generics, iteration, hashset

> SOLVED. See bottom edit if curious.

I am working on a programming assignment for my Computer Science class where we're creating an implementation for a 2D-Graphics based game that uses Quad trees. I'm having trouble with a specific part of my QuadTree implementation.

This is the attributes and constructor:

```
public class QuadTreeNode<E extends BoxIntersectable> {

protected Box region;

protected HashSet<E> items;

protected QuadTreeNode<E> northEast; // Quadrant 2, left 2
protected QuadTreeNode<E> northWest; // Quadrant 1, left 1
protected QuadTreeNode<E> southEast; // Quadrant 4, right 2
protected QuadTreeNode<E> southWest; // Quadrant 3, right 1

protected int depth;

public static final int MAX_items = 20; // # of items per node
public static final int MAX_DEPTH = 20;

public QuadTreeNode(Box bbox, int depth) {
    items = new HashSet<E>();
    northEast = northWest = southEast = southWest = null;
    this.region = bbox;
    this.depth = depth;
}
```

This is the findIntersecting method and it's recursive helper method:

```
    /**
 * Find all items intersecting a given bounding box.
 * 
 * <p>
 * Hints: Use a recursive algorithm with a helper. Create a HashSet to store
 * the items and pass it to the recursive calls.
 * </p>
 * 
 * <p>
 * Recurse on any child node whose region intersects the box. At a leaf node
 * test each item stored in the node to see if it intersects the box. If it
 * does, add it to the HashSet that is returned.
 * </p>
 * 
 * @param box
 *            The box to intersect objects with.
 * @return A set containing all of the items.
 */
public Set<E> findIntersecting(Box box) {
    Set<E> intersectingBoxes = new HashSet<>();
    if (getBoxRegion().intersects(box)) {
        findIntersectingHelper(intersectingBoxes, this, box);
    }
    return intersectingBoxes;
}

/**
 * Helper method for findIntersecting.
 * 
 * @param intersectingBoxes the set of boxes intersecting box.
 * @param root the node 
 * @param box the box to be checked for intersection.
 */
private void findIntersectingHelper(Set<E> intersectingBoxes, QuadTreeNode root, Box box) {
    // No need to check if root box region intersects box, method is only called if such occurs.
    if (root.isLeaf()) {
        for (E item : root.allItems()) {
            intersectingBoxes.add(item);
        }
    } else {
        // Call recursion on any child who intersects box.
        if (northWest.getBoxRegion().intersects(box)) {
            findIntersectingHelper(intersectingBoxes, northWest, box);
        }
        if (northEast.getBoxRegion().intersects(box)) {
            findIntersectingHelper(intersectingBoxes, northEast, box);
        }
        if (southWest.getBoxRegion().intersects(box)) {
            findIntersectingHelper(intersectingBoxes, southWest, box);
        }
        if (southEast.getBoxRegion().intersects(box)) {
            findIntersectingHelper(intersectingBoxes, southEast, box);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is in findIntersectingHelper, specifically the line:

```
for (E item : root.allItems()) {
```

The method allItems returns the attribute items as a Set. I thought this would be fine since this is iterating through a set of Es, but the compiler begs to differ. I'm getting the following compilation time error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to E

How do I fix this so that the compiler approves of what I'm trying to do?

Thanks for your assistance!

**Edit: My problem was that my recursive method call didn't generic type root. I am a dunce. My apologies to anybody whom I made facepalm.**

Comment: What type are you declaring root to have in findIntersectingHelper ?

Comment: I think it will work if you do as below for your for loop. `for (BoxIntersectable item : root.allItems()) {`. As all the items returned from root are going to be of type / subtype of `BoxIntersectable`.

Comment: I figured it out. My problem was I didn't generic type root in my recursive function call. It's working fine now.